# Не понятно как работают подсказки кода в PhpStorm

Tags: html, css, phpstorm, settings

Подскажите как сделать в PhpStorm, чтобы он подсказывал классы и id при верстке сайтов. Когда я делаю разметку на HTML и задаю для разных тегов различные классы и id, а потом перехожу в sass/css для настройки оформления, то в подсказках кода нет ни единого класса или id. Если я один раз эти классы и id использую в sass/css, то потом они уже появляются в подсказках кода. Как сделать чтобы все вновь добавленные классы и id отображались в подсказках при первом их использовании в таблицах стилей?

Comment: Возможно предпологается что вы будете писать код в другой последовательности: сначала CSS и только потом HTML

Comment: В обратной последовательности тоже не работает. Версия шторма 10

Answer (score 2):

Есть соответствующая [заявка](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-150) на JetBrains YouTrack.

Судя по комментариям, такая возможность пока что не предвидится.

Comment: Странно.. Вроде такая элементарная функция. В Dream Weaver уже данным давно такое есть. А может какой плагин есть для этой цели?

Comment: Простой поиск по репозиторию не дал результатов. Почему эта функция не реализована по умолчанию - для меня тоже непонятно. Хотя судя по тому, что заявка была создана в 2011 году и по ее активности, это мало кого интересует.

Comment: Тоже копался в настройках, но так ничего и не нашёл. Может кто плагин сделал. Поищу ещё. А то каждый раз перед использованием в sass/CSS новых классов и ID надо их сначала скопировать в HTML или в ручную написать. Как-то не удобно